Cannot change I.P. address of VLAN
Set up VLAN on eth0, worked great.
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/vlans
auto eth0.16
iface eth0.16 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth0

sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface eth0.16
static ip_address=10.20.36.2/23
static routers=10.20.37.1
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1

Made this change to dhcpcd.conf:
interface eth0.16
static ip_address=10.20.16.12/23  # changed from 10.20.26.2
static routers=10.20.17.1  # changed from 10.20.37.1
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1

Rebooted
hostname -I
192.168.x.x 10.20.36.2  // eth0.16 did not change
What do I have to do to get the I.P. address changed?

This question is similar to: How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
